# htaccess to redirect to folder, ignoring subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble creating .htaccess rules to do this
domain name is ico.[any domain name]
files are all icon files (.ico, .gif, .png, .svg) [nothing else served here, ever].
And I need the icons to be served (permanent redirects) up from folders based on the root domain, i.e.:
https://ico.example0.com/favicon.ico to https://ico.example0.com/www.example0.com/favicon.ico
https://ico.example1.com/apple-touch-icon.png to https://ico.example1.com/www.example1.com/apple-touch-icon.png
https://ico.example2.com/favicon.gif to https://ico.example0.com/www.example2.com/favicon.gif

Can this be done?
Thanks!
-Brian

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  Where are the files you are trying to serve up?  By that I mean what is the directory structure on the host computer where the files are.

Using .htaccess to redirect is pretty straightforward, but what you have asked for assumes an odd directory structure.  Maybe not.  But please show what you are trying to do.

Comment: the directory structure is:   https://ico.[anydomain.tld/www.[anydomain,tld]/favicon.ico   Its kind of a generic CDN for icon files.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can do that.

You'll need to create directories for each domain in your %DOCUMENT_ROOT% (for this I've created **www.google.com** and **www.facebook.com**:

```
root@alberta:/var/www/html# ls -ltr
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 10701 Apr 16 11:01 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 15 www-data www-data 12288 Apr 16 14:52 mantis
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 May 18 15:02 www.google.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 May 18 15:04 www.facebook.com
```

Add a rule to redirect using as base the %HTTP_HOST% (which is the domain from where the request comes). I've added the rule in my default virtualhost /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

Which results in this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
        Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I've emulated the request using CURL and it works *(The parameter **--header Host:**  tells apache which domain I am)*:

```
root@alberta:/etc/apache2/sites-available# curl --verbose --header 'Host: www.google.com' 'localhost'
```

And the answer is the document html in my www.google.com directory:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
<p>ok google.com</p>
```

The same with facebook:

```
root@alberta:/etc/apache2/sites-available# curl --verbose --header 'Host: www.facebook.com' 'localhost'
```

And the answer is the document in my www.facebook.com folder:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
<p>my facebook.com</p>
```

Cheers!

Comment: RewriteRule ^/?(.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
Throws a '500' error.